# How to use server DateTime format in DataGridViewColumn instead of system DateTime format

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datagridview, datagrid, datepicker

I have a `DataGridView` with a `DateTime` formatted column.

On load it is showing the system `DateTime` format and on click of cell it is showing server `DateTime` format. I want to always use server `DateTime` format.

If I change the system `DateTime` format, the cell value format should not change.

Example: Server `DateTime` format is `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"` whilst system `DateTime` format if I change is `"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt"`.

Comment: Look in the `Layout` event, you should be able to set the format of the column to `dd/MM/yyyy`

Answer (score 2):

Place the below code in the `Form_Load` event and change the `DataGridView` name,  `Columns[No]` and the date format as required:

```
me.dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
```